# How to set your Android App so that it automatically updates on the users' phone if I upload a new APK?

Tags: java, android, mobile, apk, auto-update

How to set your Android App so that it automatically updates on the users' phone if I upload a new APK?

Comment: That is not possible, as users have to approve app installs and upgrades. The exception is if the *user* enables an auto-update feature on the built-in distribution channel app for their device (e.g., Play Store for many).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programmatically achieve this if its the usual Google Playstore update, automatic update only happens when a user a set it in his/her Google playstore account. What you can do is to look for a way to notify the user that a new update is available and ask them to download, or better still set a form of flag that will make the app ask for upload when you push a new update

Comment: okay, I see. than I have another question. The Facebook App, Messenger, WhatsApp always updates automatically on my mobile if a new version is out, so I guess that the auto-update is enabled on my device. However, the app I created does not update. What could be the problem?

Comment: yes, i guess its auto-update. also another problem could be that you didn't update your version code, but i don't think Google play store will allow you to upload the same app with the same app version code, each time it should increase, that's what is used exactly to notify user's that there is an update available. to confirm you have the auto-update on its per app not one for all the app, make sure you visit the play store and go to `my apps` then to your app, there is a option menu to check the auto update option